Google Sheets calculate percentage of the values in the rightmost column of total values in that column
My table is as follows:



Ticker
Wanted%
Actual%
April
May
June




AAPL
30

1$
1$
150$


META
50

10$
5$
15$


MSFT
20

100$
10$
120$



My goal is to calculate the actual percentage each ticker is taking from my whole portfolio.
I'm looking for a formula to put in each cell in column C so it can calculate the whole sum of the porfolio in the rightmost column (a new column will be appended each month manually), and how much weight the current row takes out of the total.
For the example above, the Actual% would be:
| 52.6 |
| 5.2  |
| 42.1 |

Can you showcase your ideal expected output as well for the sample dataset?!

@rockinfreakshow - added


You may try:
=let(last_col,choosecols(D2:ZZ,index(match(,0/(D1:1<>"")))),
     map(last_col,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,Σ/sum(last_col)))))



It will search n' pick the the last month header in row_1 (D1:1)

